# D3.js pulling and embedding DataURI images with Promises

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, amazon-s3, data-uri

I'm building a data visualization which relies on a lot of small raster images, delivered as AWS URLs via JSON API.

This works fairly well, until I try to implement my next step, which is rendering the data visualization as a PNG to download. In the PNG, the raster images are broken.

I've understood that to solve this, I need to embed images as Data URLs.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
const companies_base64 = companies.map(c => {
  var o = Object.assign({}, c)
  o.base64 = imageToBase64(c.mimetype, c.logo)
  return o
})
```

Where `companies` is an array of objects. Here's `imageToBase64`, the Heroku app being a clone of [CORS anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere):

```
function imageToBase64(mimetype, logo) {
  var url = 'https://example.herokuapp.com/' + logo
  return d3.blob(url)
           .then(blob => blobToBase64(blob))
           .then(base64 => mimetype + base64)
           .catch(error => console.error(error))
}

function blobToBase64(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = () => {
      let dataUrl = reader.result
      let base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1]
      resolve(base64)
    }
    reader.onerror = () => {
      reject("Error")
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  })
}
```

Which results in a `Promise` being returned when calling `base64` on any of the objects in `companies_base64`, the `[[PromiseValue]]` being of course what I'm after. How am I supposed to make sure it is what gets returned so I can, ultimately, place it inside the `xlink:href` attributes of the `<image>`s in my `<svg>`?

I think that once it works and I can call `imageToBase64` wherever, it's something I want to do only when the user presses *Download*. I imagine I can do this using D3, iterating over the `<image>`s and swapping out their `xlink:href`. Or should I go about it another way?

I have also tried getting the images as objects and then converting them to base64 in my RoR backend so they come packaged with the `JSON`, via an `Image#to_base64` method. This does work, but it A) feels very wrong and B) is obviously very slow on initial load.

Thank you for your time and please bear with me as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imageToBase64` function returns a promise, not the resolved data URL. That means you have to wait before you can attach them to the `companies_base64` members. It is your choice if you do that as soon as the individual base64 string is ready, or if you wait for them all:

```
Promise.all(companies.map(c => {
     return imageToBase64(c.mimetype, c.logo)
         .then(u => Object.assign({ base64: u }, c))
         .then(/* change the image reference here one by one... */)
}))
.then(companies_base64 => /* ...or here, in a loop over the array */)
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```